# Is there a nicer way to find this number?

Tags: real-analysis

I was solving the following problem: Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be such that using euclidean norm $|x-z|=|x-y|+|y-z|$, prove that there is $t \in [0,1]$ such that $y=(1-t)x+tz$.

Well, I first noticed that $y=(1-t)x+tz$ is equivalent to have $(y-x)=t(z-x)$. Now, I've proved already that in the euclidean norm if $|u+v|=|u|+|v|$ then there is $\alpha \geq 0$ such that $v = \alpha u$. So, I've set $u =x-y$ and $v=y-z$ and use this fact to deduce that $y-z=\alpha(x-y)$. I've tried a lot to make this look like what I wanted but it wasn't possible.

So I've changed roles, I've set $u = y-z$ and $v =x-y$, then I found $x-y = \alpha(y-z)$ and so I've had the intuition to sum and subtract $x$ to make the term $z-x$ appear, getting $x-y = \alpha(y-x+x-z)$, this lead my quickly to $(y-x)=\alpha/(1+\alpha)(z-x)$. Since $t=\alpha/(1+\alpha) \in [0,1]$, this shows that such $\alpha$ exists.

The only thing making me a little confused is that I needed to take a lot of guesses and tries along this proof. It wasn't a straightforward way to find this $t$. Is there a nicer way to solve this or the way I've thought is the right way in this kind of problem: we simply take guesses trying to make appear terms we know how to relate, try those guesses and if they fail try again?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Dear user, Do you understand intuitively why this result is true?  Note that the map $t \mapsto (1-t)x + t z$ from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R^n$ exactly traces out the line segement joining $x$ and $z$,  So the result says that if the distance from $x$ to $y$ plus the distance from $y$ to $z$ equals the distance from  $x$ to $z$, then $y$ lies on the line segment joining $x$ to $z$.  Hopefully you can visualize this and see why it's true.  If this intuition is helpful, let me know and I'll post this as an answer.  On the other hand, if this intuition is already clear, but you want to know how ...

Comment: ... to convert it into an actual proof, let me know (since then obviously what I've written here isn't really an answer to your question).  Regards,

Comment: I don't how formal you want to be but that equality can happen if and only if the $x,y,z$ are colinear with $y$ staying somewhere on the line segment joining $x$ and $z$. The result is then immediate.

Comment: Thanks for the help @MattE! I knew the geometric interpretation but wans't finding a way to use it properly. Indeed the only solution using geometry I've found was to parametrize the segment between $x$ and $z$ with a curve $\alpha$, reparametrize by arc-length and put in the parameter the distance from $x$ to $y$. It worked, but I've continued trying for a much simpler way. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Dear user, You're welcome.  It looks like ShreevatsaR found a good way to combine the geometric perspective with the work you'd already done.  Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a tiny amount of looking at what your statement means geometrically helps here.

The question asks you to prove that if $|x-z| = |x-y| + |y-z|$, then $y = (1-t)x + tz$ for some $t \in [0, 1]$. This is the algebraic statement.  Geometrically, what this means is that if the distance from $x$ to $z$ is the sum of distances from $x$ to $y$ and from $y$ to $z$, then **$y$ is on the line (segment) joining $x$ to $z$.** (The geometric meaning of $y = (1-t)x + tz$ is that $y$ is on the line segment joining $x$ to $z$.)

You've already shown that if $|u + v| = |u| + |v|$, then $v = \alpha u$. The geometric meaning of $v = \alpha u$ is that $v$ is a scalar multiple of $u$. In the new problem, with $|x - z| = |x - y| + |y-z|$, as you observed, it's of the same form $|u + v| = |u| + |v|$ with $u = x - y$ and $v = y-z$ (the first thing you tried), so $v = y - z$ is a scalar multiple of $u = x - y$. Think about that for a moment: this means that the line from $y$ to $z$ has the same direction as the line from $x$ to $y$, which already means that $y$ is on the line joining $x$ to $z$: this is already a proof, you are actually done (modulo proving that $y$ is inside the line segment, i.e., $t \in [0, 1]$). But to find an algebraic expression for $t$, you'd go about it as follows.

Note that your result with $u$ and $v$ gives $v = \alpha u$ or here, $y - z = \alpha(x - y)$. Just solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ and $z$! You have
$$ y - z = \alpha(x - y) = \alpha x - \alpha y,$$
so collecting all the $y$ terms on the left-hand side,
$$ \alpha y + y = \alpha x + z$$
$$ (\alpha + 1)y = \alpha x + z$$
and dividing throughout by $(\alpha + 1)$ (because you want the form "$y = $ something"), we get
$$ y = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + 1}x + \frac{1}{\alpha + 1}z$$
which is of the form you want, with $t = \frac{1}{\alpha + 1}$. No guesswork required; everything worked out fine, the way we knew it would.

When doing these things, there are often (at least) two perspectives: the algebraic and the geometric. It will help you to have in mind the "glossary" between the two, and frequently (at every step if possible) translate back and forth between the two perspectives.

Comment: Thanks for the help @ShreevatsaR. This was my first try but I didn't realize in the end that this could be written as $y = x + t(z-x)$. Now I've found out that it can be, so everything is fine. Thanks for your aid!

Comment: @user1620696: Actually, with the geometric perspective, you would have guessed $t=\frac{1}{\alpha+1}$ without any calculation: note that if $x,y,z$ are in a line, with the y—z distance being $\alpha$ times the x—y distance, then to get from $x$ to $z$ you have to cover some distance $d$ (to reach $y$) and then some more distance $\alpha d$, so automatically, the latter distance is $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + 1}$ times the total distance. In other words: you should understand that in the expression $y = (1-t)x + tz$, what $t$ really means is "what fraction of the x—z distance is the y—z distance?"

Answer (score 0):

The sleek functional analysis solution is $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Hilbert space $\implies$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ is uniformly convex $\implies$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ is strictly convex $\iff$ your property holds.